# Translation issue MS Exchange and Samsung Tab 2 10.1

Tags: exchange, localization, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I recently purchased a Samsung tab 2 10.1.  Everything seems to be working fine except that it does not properly sync with Outlook calendar and contacts -- the text on the notes section of both the calendar and contacts do not translate properly in Samsung Galaxy.  This is what I see:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="Generator" content=Microsoft Exchange Server"> 
<!--converted from rtf--> 
<style>
<!--.EmailQuote {margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid;}-->
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<font face="Times New Roman, serif" size="3"> 
<div style="margin-bottom: 6pt; ">
```

Another instance of this infamous HTML code that shows up:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name=”Generator” content=”Microsoft Exchange Server”> 
<!-- converted from text --> 
<style>
<!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } -->
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<font size=”2”>
<div class=”PlainText”>Monday, January 11, 2010 3:53 PM:<br> <br>
```

Other devices like Motorola Droid4, Palm and iPhone have no problem syncing with the exchange.  It's just this Samsung tablet that can't seem to sync properly.  I called Samsung, Verizon and our Exchange server specialist.  Samsung and Verizon asked me to do a factory reset.  The problem not solved.  I got a new Samsung unit, the problem remained.  No one seems to know what, why and how.  Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, the gibberish that I typed to show what comes up on the notes section of my screen did not appear on my issue above.

Comment: Did you leave out the picture...? You've left it hanging at *This is what I see:* ....

Comment: This is what I see:   <html><head><meta name=”Generator” content=”Microsoft Exchange Server”>
<!-- converted from text -->
<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head>
<body>
<font size=”2”><div class=”PlainText”>Monday, January 11, 2010 3:53 PM:<br>
<br>

Comment: ahhhh... what happened was, that this forum's web page parser mis-interpreted the actual code you saw and posted into this question which resulted in a blank... Have edited to illustrate... :) *Protip*, click on the '{}' in the toolbar when editing to enable the contents to not be actually interpreted by this site's parser :)